# Значение из файла в значение для команды

Tags: c++, файлы, консоль, текст, color

Я пишу библиотеку на C++. Что она делает? Задаётся файл с числами от 1 до 256 (вид: 70 117 32 и т.д.). Мне нужно чтобы значения каждого этого числа вводились в константу num и вводилось в команду `termcolor::color<num>` (соответственно --> termcolor::color<70>, termcolor::color<117>, termcolor::color<32> и т.д.). Пытался сгенерировать это через нейросеть, но упёрся в проблему константного значения

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib/termcolor.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void init() {
    system("chcp 65001 >nul");
}

void draw(string filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Не удалось открыть файл." << endl;
        return;
    }

    map<int, string> colorMap;
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        int color;
        if (iss >> color)
        {
            // Здесь мы можете определить соответствующий цвет для каждого числа
            colorMap[color] = termcolor::color<color>;
        }
    }
```